# Data transfer from USB system to RS232 system

Tags: windows-7

I need to transfer the data from system with USB to system with RS232. Not allowed to add RS232 system in the network. What steps I can follow and do I need special device /cable apart from USB to serial cable. Thanks.

Comment: It might depend on the 'flavour'/voltage of RS232, and the specific devices. More details would be nice.

Comment: Thanks. This is in terms of Medical Scenario. Person wants to connect her laptop to main system which only has USB drive. The laptop has just RS232. Now the situation is, there is a device which is connected to a laptop which needs voltage which will be generated from main system so user wants a connection between her system with USB and laptop with RS232.